# Flutter - Download image from URL and upload to firebase storage without storing anything on device

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I know we can use https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader to download an image file and store it to local storage and upload that file then to firebase storage, but I don't want to store anything on local storage.

> (Here I mean downloading an image from an external URL, that is not
> already stored/uploaded to the Firebase storage.)

Also, I don't want to store the image URL directly to the database (because if the image isn't available on that URL in the future that causes problems), so I want to download and store the image file.

Is something like this possible or is it a must to store the image first to achieve this?

Thanks, all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "without storing anything on device".  It's unclear what your use case is that forces this requirement.

Comment: @DougStevenson
Basically, I don't want to request local storage access from the device and be able to download images over the network and upload them to firebase storage. Hope this clears the use case.

Comment: The question is unclear. The image URL stored in Firebase is to the URL of the image *in Firebase Storage*, so it would always be available. If it's deleted, you would need to URL from firebase to know where it is to delete it in the first place so then the image and the URL would be deleted together. Secondly, you are free to upload an image from disk or from memory, both are covered in the documentation - that meets the requirement of "without storing anything on device". Perhaps clarifying the question will prevent it from being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way of doing this, maybe it was obvious as it was super simple and I just didn't know it. Anyways, will keep the question posted, in case it becomes helpful to someone else.

The following code snippet does exactly what I want:

*(Showing only two important imports here)*

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

try {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("<<image_url>>");

    Response resp = await get(uri);
    Reference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("some_folder").child("image_name.png");
    SettableMetadata metadata = SettableMetadata(contentType: "image/png");
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await ref.putData(resp.bodyBytes, metadata);
    _logger.info(await ref.getDownloadURL());
  } catch (e) {
    _logger.shout(e);
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with your question *Download image from URL* - where is the coding solution for that? This code just uploads data from memory and is covered, with example code, in the documentation [Upload Data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-raw-data), can you maybe clarify the answer with how this is a solution and what's different from the documentation?

Comment: @Jay
The question is - to download an image from a certain URL (external, not from Firebase storage), and then upload it (the image data) directly to the storage without storing anything on the device storage.

The link to the documentation you have provided does not show exactly what I have provided in my answer - see :
 Response resp = await get(uri);

Maybe it was obvious and I just didn't know it, that is what I have mentioned in my answer also, just trying to learn and share dude. Happy holidays.

Comment: Understood - I was looking for the code to do the downloading part as well then uploading it. Now that you explained it - it's more clear. Thank you.