# How to save an Image obtained from Image.network to firebase all within Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Basically I have the following widget Image.network(imageUrl) and I want to create a file from that imageUrl and save it within firebase.

Basically from Image.network(imageUrl) -> create png or jpg file -> store it in firebase. The imageUrl is created by an API request call within the flutter app, so there is no way of obtaining the url beforehand.

Comment: This use-case will take multiple steps: 1) [download the data from the URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+download+image+from+url) to the local system (either in memory or on disk), 2) [upload the resulting data to Cloud Storage through Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files). Did you try either of those steps already? What problem did you run into?

Comment: Thank you so much!! just went to those links and figure out the solution was already there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70478077/flutter-download-image-from-url-and-upload-to-firebase-storage-without-storing